# Error: DPI-1002: invalid dpiConn handle: Nodejs, Oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle, plsql, node-oracledb

I have the following API, the API is inserting into a table based on user selection from the client. User can select different material belonging to same experiment. In my payload, I have materials as array, experiment as string. I tried several ways to resolve my error. Following was the last try:

```
app.post("/insertMaterials", (req, res) => {

for (let mat of req.body["material"]) {
    try {
    oracledb.getConnection(
        {
        user: "some_user",
        password: "some_pw",
        connectString: "someConnStr",
        },
        function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("1" + err);
            return;
        }
        connection.execute(
            "INSERT INTO MATERIALS (ID, MAT_NAME, EXPR) VALUES((SELECT max(ID) + 1 FROM MATERIALS), :1, :2)",
            [mat, req.body["experiment"]],
            (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error("log " + err);
            }
            connection.commit();
            connection.close();
            }
        );
        }
    );
    } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    }
}
return res.status(200).json({
    title: "SUCCESS: Materials Inserted",
});

});
```

I always get:
*****triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^
[Error: DPI-1002: invalid dpiConn handle] { errorNum: 0, offset: 0 }*****

Before I had a separate function of the block inside the for loop and I also tried with execeuteMany. Still same error. After trying lot other ways and reading in internet, I couldn't solve the issue. Except for finally catching *uncaughtException* and logging the error:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (error, next) => {
let date = new Date()
errorLogStream.write(`Date: ${date}. Err: ${error.stack} \n`)
return
})
```

By catching this exception, my program does not break anymore and data is always inserted. But it would be great to know how and when this is raised and how this can be resolved or where if I am doing a mistake.

**UPDATE**

*Payload example: {'material': ['F99999.7', 'J84845.4'], 'experiment': 'NA32R'}*

**Function:**

```
async function addMatToExpr(exp, mat) {
  let connection;
  try {
  connection = await oracledb.getConnection(
      {
        user: "some_user",
        password: "some_pw",
        connectString: "someConnStr",
      });
  result = await connection.execute("INSERT INTO MATERIALS (ID, 
  MAT_NAME, EXPR) VALUES((SELECT max(ID) + 1 FROM MATERIALS), :1, :2)", 
  [exp, mat], { autoCommit: true })

  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(404).json({
      title: error,
    });
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close()
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**API:**

```
app.post("/insertMaterials", (req, res) => {
    for (let mat of req.body["materials"]) {
      addMatToExpr(req.body["experiment"], mat)
    }
  });
```

Added the async/await function and the api that calls the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'await' the Oracle function calls so each completes before continuing.  Currently the connection is being closed before the statement is executed.

See all the node-oracledb [documentation](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html) and [examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples).

E.g.

```
async function run() {
  let connection;

  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);

    result = await connection.execute(sql, binds, options);
    console.dir(result, { depth: null });

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it still gives uncaughtException, I already tried with async/await before posting this question. The difference in this API is that it has a for loop. However if I have only one record to insert, it does not gives the error.

Comment: You need to update your question with a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, thanks for guiding me, i have updated the minimum viable solution

Comment: I am not sure how to run your code.  What are the files called, what modules do they require, etc.  I do still see calls like `connection.commit();  connection.close();` that are wrong - those calls need to be run sequentially, not in parallel because the way they are written the commit may happen after the connection is close.  I strongly suggest rewriting to use the async/await style of programming because the callback style is error prone.

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding the for loop inside the function itself instead of letting function run in the for loop